# Wix: How to get 'TargetFramework' | 'TargetFrameworkVersion' of the application beeing installed / packed

Tags: .net-core, wix

I have a `WPF` project which `TargetFramework` is `net461`. The output folder is `my.wpf.app\bin\Release\net461`. Is it possible to get the `TargetFramework` or `net461` value in the msbuild or wix build pipeline?

I need it to heat the directory and don't want to write `net461` in the `my.wpf.app.setup.wixproj` file.

**my.wpf.app.csproj**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
<Project/>
```

**my.wpf.app.setup.wixproj**

```xml
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Gathering libraries..." Importance="high" />
    <CreateItem Include="..\my.wpf.app\bin\$(Configuration)\net461\*.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="LibraryFiles" />
    </CreateItem>
</Target>
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
package:Client:
    stage: pack
    tags:
        - msbuild-ps
        - wix-ps
    script:
        - MSBuild.exe /maxcpucount /nologo /p:Configuration=ClientInstaller /p:WarningLevel=0 /p:BuildProjectReferences=false "src\$env:SLNNAME.sln"
        - xcopy /s /y /i src\my.wpf.app.setup\bin\Release\*.msi .\
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - .\*.msi
        expire_in: 1 day
```

Comment: Do you reference main project in wix project? You can try to pass `TargetFramework` as command line at build, if it fits your needs

Comment: Yes, the main project is referenced. But because this is a `dotnet` project, this is not built by `msbuild` but separately. Can you tell me how to pass the value via commandline? I do not want to write `net461` in the `gitlab-ci.yml` (then I could also write the value directly in the `wixproj`.).

Comment: try the following `/p:Configuration=ClientInstaller;p:TargetFramework=net461`

Comment: Then I could also write the value directly in the `wixproj`. I want it dynamically 